# Promise returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an NPM package, however when I pass the image path to the module, it returns `null`.

This is the code of the `.upload()` method:

```js
module.exports = (image) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (!image) throw new TypeError('No image provided.');

        const request = require('request'),
            fs = require('fs'),
            options = {
                method: "POST",
                url: "https://kim.kieranhowland.co.uk/api/upload",
                port: 443,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
                formData : {
                    "image": fs.createReadStream(image)
                }
            };

        request(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) throw (err);
            
            try {
                let parsed = JSON.parse(body);

                parsed.url = `https://kim.kieranhowland.co.uk/uploads/${parsed.info.image_id}/`

                resolve(parsed);
            } catch(error) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });

    })
}
```

This is what I use to test the package:

```js
const kim = require('kim-api')
const path = require('path');

console.log(path.join(__dirnane, 'check.png')); // returns image path

kim.upload(path.join(__dirname, 'check.png')).then(img => {
    console.log('Image url: ' + img.url);
}).catch(err => console.error(err))

kim.uploads().then(data => {
    console.log('Total uploads: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Code Things\test-kim\check.png
null
Total uploads: {"status":200,"data":{"uploads":4622}}
```

- The file path **is** correct.
- The `.upload()` method returns `null`.
- The `.uploads()` method returns the expected output.

Would anyone happen to know what is making my code not return the parsed output, or what is making it return `null`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you're exporting just a function, not an object with an `upload` method. How are you exporting the `uploads` function?

Comment: From what I can see here, I´d assume that the code throws an exception anywhere which is null (`console.log(err)`). Otherwise your `console.log('Image url: ' + img.url);` would print something like `image url: null`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if (err) throw (err);` part of request be within the `try` block so it can be catched and rejects the promise?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was dumb.

```js
} catch(error) {
    reject(err);
}
```

This part of the code is obviously not written correctly. Changing `err` into `error` allowed me to actually view and fix the error. Sorry!